# Parallelizing a function in C OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, multicore

How do i parallelize this function in OpenMP for C

```
int zeroRow(int**A,int n) {
int i, j, sum, num = 0;
for(i= 0;i< n;i++) {
  sum = 0;
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    sum += A[i][j];
  }
 if(sum == 0) {
   num++;
  }
}
return num;
}
```

I did this check if this is the right procedure.

```
int zeroRow(int**A,int n) {
int  num = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:num);
for(int i= 0;i< n;i++) {
  int sum = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
   sum += A[i][j];
   }
  if(sum == 0) {
    num++;
  }
}
return num;
}
```

please tell me if what i have done is right or wring i have parallelized the outer loop using reduction and a separate num is given to each thread.

Comment: okay i did indent it the first time probably something went wrong when i pressed ctrl-k,now i indednted it manually.@H2Co3

Comment: Looks okay to me.  Is there a problem?

Comment: It seems correct indeed, however, it's good to bear in mind that if `j` was defined outside the parallel region (e.g., in C), it should definitely be set to private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks correct parallelized.

The only thing you should add is a term specifying the use of A. 
 You rely that the default case is shared. You should explicitly name the status with

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:num) default(shared)
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:num) shared(A)
```

also you do not need to write a semicolon (;) at the end of the `pragma` line (but writing it would be no error)

Comment: As far as I know variables defined outside of a parallel block are shared by default so `default(shared)` and shared(A) are unnecessary.  The only exception are variables used to parallelize a loop.  They are made private

Comment: I said nothing in contrary but you make faults in respect to shared/private status easier if you rely on this default default case; safest way would be name everything and use default(none)